# How to do an action if an optional boolean is true?

Tags: java, java-8, boolean, option-type

In Java 8, I have a variable, holding an optional boolean.

I want an action to be executed, if the optional is not empty, and the contained boolean is true.

I am dreaming about something like `ifPresentAndTrue`, here a full example:

```
import java.util.Optional;

public class X {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Optional<Boolean> spouseIsMale = Optional.of(true);
    spouseIsMale.ifPresentAndTrue(b -> System.out.println("There is a male spouse."));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For good order

```
if (spouseIsMale.orElse(false)) {
    System.out.println("There is a male spouse.");
}
```

Clear.

Comment: Would be nice though to have the possibility to ditch that unnecessary code "orElse(false)". It's like writing "if (myBoolVariable == true)" - I never write "== true" ... But nevertheless, I also use this exact code as it is the cleanest and fast and easy to understand.

Comment: @BAER I am allergic against `== true` too. Looked at Java 9, but that does not look better: `spouseIsMale.stream().filter(Function::identity).forEach(b-> System.out.println("There is a male spouse."));`

Comment: You can filter an Optional too you know.

Comment: Is there a way to throw an exception if false? - in java8 way - instead using else block

Comment: @Gibbs https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow-java.util.function.Supplier-

Comment: It throws if there is no value. But it will always have either true/false. Isn't?

Comment: Here not boolean but Boolean is used. Maybe you are looking for something different. Good luck.

Answer (score 17):

It is possible to achieve that behaviour with `.filter(b -> b)`:

```
spouseIsMale.filter(b -> b).ifPresent(b -> System.out.println("There is a male spouse."));
```

However, it costs some *brain execution time* seconds to understand what is going on here.

Comment: @JoopEggen `filter(Functions.identity())` does not work, the types are not compatible.

Comment: Thanks, boolean, not Boolean.

Answer (score 11):

For those looking to write this without traditional
`if(condition){ //Do something if true; }`

```
Optional.of(Boolean.True)
    .filter(Boolean::booleanValue)
        .map(bool -> { /*Do something if true;*/ })
```

Answer (score 4):

All of the above answers combined:

```
spouseIsMale
.filter(Boolean::booleanValue)
.ifPresent(
  value -> System.out.println("There is a male spouse.")
);
```

Answer (score 1):

What I usually use is (I also check for the null value):

```
Optional.ofNullable(booleanValue).filter(p -> p).map(m -> callFunctionWhenTrue()).orElse(doSomethingWhenFalse());
```

This has three parts:

1. `Optional.ofNullable(booleanValue)` - Checks for null value
2. `.filter(p -> p).map(m -> callFunctionWhenTrue())` - Filter checks for boolean value true and appyly the map function
3. `.orElse(doSomethingWhenFalse())` - This part will execute if the boolean value is false

Comment: It should be `orElseGet` instead of `orElse`.

Comment: It throws the exception in case `booleanValue` is null.                                            
```Error:
|  incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
|      java.lang.Object cannot be converted to boolean```

Answer (score -1):

You can shrink it a little bit.

```
Optional<Boolean> spouseIsMale= Optional.of(true);
spouseIsMale.ifPresent(v -> { if (v) System.out.println("There is a male spouse.");});
```